# Root symbol on newtxmath

Tags: newtxmath, sqrt, root

I'm using the newtxmath package, but I don't like the symbol layout for the roots. I would like to go back to the root symbol of computer modern font.

any command line to do it, after \usepackage{newtxmath}?

Answer (score 5):

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathRadical{\sqrtsign}{cmsymbols}{"70}{cmlargesymbols}{"70}

\begin{document}

$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{a^5}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove the three lines starting with `\Declare...` you get back the NewTX radicals

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, egreg. I really appreciate your concern and effort to post brilliant answers!!!